# Can FME georeference dwg CAD files?

Tags: georeferencing, fme-form

Due to problems with other software, I am trying to find altervative software in order to georeference DWG Images without a defined coordinate system attatched to them. They are digitized to scale 1:1 and are therefore the upper left coordinate is located in GIS Software at 0 0.

I have FME 2015 (soon to be FME 2016) but cannot see any georeferencing tools.

Comment: Yes, FME can do that.  I think this may answer your question:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92270/workflow-to-convert-a-dwg-cad-file-to-a-shapefile  & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/ways-to-transform-from-dwg-dxf-to-gis-experiences-are-welcome & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-import-a-dwg-into-a-qgis-project/32761#32761  also if you have Autocad Map3D handy, it will do this quite easily as well.  Also this may interest you : http://mms.nps.gov/gis/applications/documents/cadgis_rev1d.pdf

Comment: If ArcGIS is crashing, there may be a significant issue with the data, which changing applications won't address.

Comment: What version are you using ? I have a lot of dwg files that I am doing georeferencing on ArcGIS 10.3.1 and it works fine.

Comment: @RobertBuckley can you edit the question to be more specific with versions of ArcGIS and FME you have available please.

Comment: Cannot see Georeferencing Tools? - They are there just under different terminology try AffineWarper http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/affinewarper.htm and/or RubberSheeter http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rubbersheeter.htm works with Vector and Raster Datasets

Answer (score 4):

***AffineWarper***

> Performs warping operations on the spatial coordinates of features. It is used to adjust a set of observed input features according to a spatial transform defined by a set of control vectors. This transformer computes an affine (scale, rotation, and offset) transformation based on Control vector features and applies this transformation to the Observed features to generate output, and produces good corrections when the entire set of Observed data requires a single transformation.
>
> Each Control feature represents a control vector whose start point is
>   at some location in the original Observed data space, and whose end
>   point is at the corresponding location in the desired output data
>   space. The control vector represents the correction required to go
>   from the observed vertex to the desired vertex. (Control vectors with
>   only one point are interpreted as a requirement that this location not
>   change from the observed dataset to the reference dataset. This is
>   often referred to as a tie point.)

http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rubbersheeter.htm

Also see

***Affiner***

> Performs an affine transformation on the coordinates of the feature.
>
> An affine transformation preserves lines and parallelism in geometry.
>   That is, any lines that were parallel before the transformation are
>   parallel after the transformation. In addition, if a number of points
>   falling on a straight line are transformed, the resulting coordinates
>   will fall on a straight line in the new coordinate system.
>
> Affine transformations include translations, rotations, scalings, and
>   reflections.

http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/affiner.htm

More info via the Knowledge Center 
https://knowledge.safe.com/